# Inline JqGrid save button click issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, inline, inline-editing

I was brainstorming almost a day on how to invoke my MVC controller action with inline edit jQgrid save button.
Please see the below screenshot
[image]

I have tried the following configuration for jqGrid

```
$("#tbl-items").CreateGrid({
                url: '@Url.Action("ItemList", "Item")',
                editurl: '@Url.Action("Create", "Item")',
                jsonReader: { id: "ItemID" },
                prmNames: { id: "ItemID" },
                colNames: ['Item ID', Item Name],
                colModel: [{ name: 'ItemID', index: 'ItemID', sorttype: 'integer', hidden: true, key: true },
                   { name: 'ItemName', index: 'ItemName', sortable: true, autowidth: true, shrinkToFit: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'] }, editable: true }],
                gridCompleteCallback: function () {
                    //Code to bind my custom edit and delete button as per the requirement
                },
                container: "#container-item",
                server: true,
                pagerID: "#itempager",
                sortName: 'ItemName',
                sortorder: 'asc',
                loadingText: 'Loading please wait',
                noRecordText: 'Not records found'
            });
```

In order to override the save event I have tried the following script

```
 function saveItem(action) {
                return {
                    url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Item")', // Url to my MVC controller
                    onclickSubmit: function (params) {
                        var list = $("#tbl-items");
                        var selectedRow = list.getGridParam("selrow");
                        // Code 
                    }
                };
            }

$("#tbl-items").jqGrid('navGrid', '#itempager',
            {
                //add: false,
                edit: false,
                del: false
            },
            saveItem('PUT')
        );
        $("#tbl-items").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#itempager',
            {
                edit: false,
                add: true, 
            });
```

I know I have done something wrong in my jqGrid configuration. Can anyone correct me in fixing my issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is clear: you mix form editing options with inline editing options. To gives you exact advice I need to know **which version of jqGrid you use and which fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?

Comment: @Oleg I am using JqGrid 4.5.1

Comment: I have to go away fro an hour. Look first of all to `editParams` option of [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav). I'll write the answer later.

Comment: @Oleg Tried but no luck.

Comment: OK, I'm back now. Please describe, which navigator buttons with which URLs and which HTTP methods you want use. Your code calls `navGrid` with `edit: false, del: false`. So it adds Add form editing button, Refresh and Search. Then you call `inlineNav` with `edit: true, add: true` (which are default) and `save: true, cancel: true` which are default too. As the result you will have navigator bar with two Add buttons (one form editing, one inline editing) and one Edit button (inline editing). Is it what you want? Which URLs need be set for Add ('@Url.Action("Create", "Item")') and which for Edit?

Comment: The next question: is the usage of retro version jqGrid 4.5.1 your requirement or you can migrate to new version the latest [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or to at least jqGris 4.6?

Comment: I need to set just the add form editing button. Its was a mistake Sorry. I have updated my post with `edit : false` .You are correct the url for Add method is ('@Url.Action("Create", "Item")'). HTTP method used is POST.

4.5.1 is our requirement. We cannot change the version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Add button of the **form editing** you **don't need to use `inlineNav` at all**. You need use only `navGrid` with the corresponding parameters. The method `navGrid` adds some buttons and it calls the corresponding jqGrid method on click on the corresponding button of navigator bar. The full list of parameters of `navGrid` described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) and it looks as

```
$("#tbl-items").jqGrid("navGrid", "#itempager", navGridOptions,
    prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView);
```

`navGridOptions` will be used to specify the options of `navGrid` itself, like `{edit: false, del: false}`, which you use. The next parameter (you use `saveItem('PUT')`) specify the options of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) method which will be called on click on Edit button of navigator bar. You use `edit: false` option of `navGrid` and the parameter will be ignored. The next parameter specify the options of `editGridRow` called on click on Add button. You don't specified any options so the default options will be used. jqGrid will uses `editurl` as the option.

To save the new row one need to press on Submit button of form editing. **No Save button is needed**. It will be used only for inline editing in the user first clicks on Add/Edit buttons added by `inlineNav` and then the user need to click on Save button for saving the changes. Because you wrote that you  "need to set just the add form editing button", you should remove `inlineNav`, which will remove unneeded Save button from the navigator bar.

**UPDATED:** If you do need to use **inline editing** and no form editing then you should use `navGrid` in the form which add no Add button and then use `inlineNav` which add Add button and which specify `url` option in both `editParams` and `addParams.addRowParams` options. The usage of both options is required because you use old jqGrid 4.5.1, which contains buggy `inlineNav`. Nevertheless I hope that the below code will work:

```
$("#tbl-items").jqGrid('navGrid', '#itempager',
    {
        add: false,
        edit: false,
        del: false
    }
);
$("#tbl-items").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#itempager',
    {
        edit: false,
        add: true, 
        editParams: {
            keys: true,
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Item")'
        },
        addParams: {
            addRowParams: {
                keys: true,
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Item")'
            }
        }
    }
);
```

I added `keys: true` which allows to save the row by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I recommend you to update to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) to have less problems and to be able to use simplified options for inline editing described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods).

Comment: I have tried navGrid but the navigation with add button doesn't appears. The navigation appears only when I used inlineGrid
I have done as follows `$("#tbl-items").jqGrid('navGrid', '#itempager', {add : true },{}, {id:"btnAdd"} )` . Have I gone wrong somewhere

Comment: @Jayaraj.K: Probably you use some old project, which developed somebody else and the code contains setting of `$.jgrid.nav` with `add: false`. The **default** value of `add` option of `navGrid` is `true`. In any way explicit usage of `$("#tbl-items").jqGrid('navGrid', '#itempager', {add : true });` should work too. I still don't understand what is your current problem. Is Add button work? Do you see Add form on click on Add button? Is the URL `@Url.Action("Create", "Item")` be called if one clicks on Submit button of Add form?

Comment: @Jayaraj.K: If you click on Add button on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick.htm) you will see how **form editing** works (locally of cause). [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons0-fa4.htm) shows **both** form editing and inline editing in one navigator toolbar. Save button works **only in case of usage inline editing**. You should decide what editing mode you really need and to use the corresponding method and options.

Comment: In the [Demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons0-fa4.htm)
the second mode is my requirement. I tried navGrid that doesn't really work for me. inlineNav appeared to be fine, but the error(**Resource cannot be found**) showed in the screenshot while clicking the save button is the real issue that I am facing.

Comment: @Jayaraj.K: What you mean under "the second mode"? Do you mean the second "+" button? The first "+" button uses [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing), the second "+" button uses [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing). I asked you before **explicitly** what mode you need and you answered:  **I need to set just the add form editing button**. I wrote my answer based on your statement. Is it wrong and you do need inline editing instead? In the case you need use `editParams` option of `inlineNav`.

Comment: @Jayaraj.K. If you **really** need to use inline editing Add button in old jqGrid 4.5.1 then your code should be like: `$("#tbl-items").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#itempager', {edit: false, editParams: {url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Item")'}, addParams: {addRowParams: {url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Item")'}}});`. The old jqGrid 4.5.1 have buggy code of `inlineNav` (which is fixed in more recent version) and one have to specify `url` twice: one time inside of `editParams` (which will work in Save button) and the second time in `addParams.addRowParams` if `keys: true` option is used too.

Comment: @Jayaraj.K: I appended my answer with the part **UPDATED** for the case that you do need to use inline editing and no form editing.

Comment: One more query I want to ask you is I have a viewmodel as parameter in my Create action of MVC controller . I want to assigned the values enter in the inline textbox to my viewmodel properties Eg: I have xxViewModel with property ItemName. I know I have to use `extraparam` attribute in my `inlineNav`. I just want to know how can I get the inline textbox value in `extraparam`

Comment: I just want to know is there other way other than $('#textboxID').val(); in jQuery

Comment: @Jayaraj.K: I think it's better that you open new question where you describe the problem more detailed on an example. I don't understand what you exactly need and how you implemented the model currently. I suppose that you mean the value from the column of jqGrid and not some property from view model. I suppose that you need the feature which not exist in `inlineNav` and `editRow` in **old jqGrid version**. In any way you should describe what you need exactly.