# Cast Inline JqGrid dropdown value to MVC viewmodel

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, inline-editing

From reference of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383724/inline-jqgrid-save-button-click-issue), I have added a drop select in the inline JqGrid. I have configured the dropdown as follows

```
$("#tbl-items").CreateGrid({
url: // MVC controller action url,
colNames: ['Item ID', 'Item Name', 'Gender',....],
colModel: [
{ name: 'ItemID', index: 'ItemID', sorttype: 'integer', hidden: true, key: true },
{name: 'ItemName', index: 'ItemName', sortable: true, autowidth: true, shrinkToFit: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'] }, editable: true},
 {name: 'Gender', index: 'Gender', sortable: true, autowidth: true, shrinkToFit: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'] }, editable: true,
                   edittype: "select",
                   formatter: 'select',
                   editoptions: {
                       dataUrl: // Url to get the list of Gender Item from the MVC controller,
                       buildSelect:
                            function (response) {
                                var data = JSON.parse(response)
                                    s = "<select>"; s += '<option value="0">--Select Gender--</option>';
                                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                        
                                        s += '<option value="' + item.GenderTypeID + '">' + item.GenderTypeName + '</option>';
                                })
                                s += '</select>';
                                return s;
                            }
                   }                  
               },


});
```

Now I am trying to post the selected value to my view model. My view model is as follows.

```
 public class CreateItemViewModel
 {
   public int ItemID { get; set; }
   public string ItemName { get; set; }
   public int GenderTypeId { get; set; }
 }
```

I am trying to post to my action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateItemViewModel itemModel)
{
   // Code
}
```

But my bad luck the value is not getting assigned to **GenderTypeId** property . Can anyone able to identify where I have gone wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to give the element a name attribute to match your model property name - `<select name="GenderTypeId">`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke for your quick response. I tried adding the name attribute. But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean _it doesn't work_? A form control without a `name` attribute will not post back its value.

Comment: Yes @StephenMuecke. I got your point. I tried renaming name: 'Gender' as `name: 'GenderTypeId'` in colModel which make the <select name="GenderTypeId"> as you said . But on post back I am getting the value as null.

Comment: @Jayaraj.K: An example of **test data for the grid and the data returned from `dataUrl`** would be very helpful. The usage of `name: 'GenderTypeId'` in `colModel` is really required. I recommend you to use Fiddler or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome (choose Network tab after strarting with F12) to make HTTP trace. You just wrote that "on post back I am getting the value as null" (probably 0 because it's `int`?). Do you have 0 inside of `Create` method? What you see in the HTTP POST exactly? Moreover you should **always write in the question, which version and fork of jqGrid you use**.

Comment: @Jayaraj.K: It would be helpful is you remove the garbage from `colModel`. The `index` can be removed because it have the same value as `name`. `sortable: true` is default value and cab be removed too. `colModel` don't support `autowidth: true, shrinkToFit: true` properties. `autowidth` and `shrinkToFit` are **options of jqGrid** and can be included on the same level like `colNames` or `colModel`, but not inside  of `colModel`. `shrinkToFit: true` is default value and can be removes (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) "Default" column).

Comment: Sorry, Its was my mistake. The GenderTypeID which I used was GUID when I changed the datatype to GUID it worked. I will closed the post.

Comment: Sorry guys, Thanks for your precious time to guide me to track my bug

Answer (score 0):

Well, your column name should be GenderTypeId.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, But I have already rectified the issue and I have commented it in by post.

Comment: Dude, you didn't get me, your column Name is Gender which is wrong and it should be {name: GenderTypeId